# TextArea not allowing to enter the text as needed

Tags: codenameone

Textarea not allowing me to enter the text as I wanted. It stops in the middle and not allowing me to add any text. If I close the keyboard and start to edit again, it will allow for some time and again stops. You can refer the screenshots.Please advise if anyone encounter same issue.

code:

```
TextArea comment;
    if (Display.getInstance().isTablet()) {
        comment = new TextArea(8, 450);
    } else {
        comment = new TextArea(5, 250);
    }
    comment.setHint("Enter Comments/ Feedback");
    comment.setGrowByContent(false);
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `setMaxSize(65536)` or something similar to set the input size to something larger than the default.